# How do I set a countdown timer to end after 24hrs

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to set a countdown timer to end after 24hrs. This is the code I'm using for the timer so far:

```
countdown: {
    // Possible options are 'default' or 'piechart'
    type: 'default',
    // The date when the countdown started. Used by the progress bars. 24 Hour format (00 to 23): Month Day, Year Hours:Minutes
    startDate: new Date(),
    // The target date we're counting down to. 24 Hour format (00 to 23): Month Day, Year Hours:Minutes
    targetDate: new Date("startDate"+1)
},
```

Initially, the code that came with  the template is;

```
countdown: {
    // Possible options are 'default' or 'piechart'
    type: 'default',
    // The date when the countdown started. Used by the progress bars. 24 Hour format (00 to 23): Month Day, Year Hours:Minutes
    startDate: new Date("November 1, 2013 00:00"),
    // The target date we're counting down to. 24 Hour format (00 to 23): Month Day, Year Hours:Minutes
    targetDate: new Date("July 20, 2014 11:13")
},
```

I want the countdown to start everyday and end after 24hrs, that's why i removed the date for the start date. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the problem is... what doesn't function?

Comment: new Date(), is it giving the same format as "November 1, 2013 00:00" ??

Comment: The second code i pasted is working fine but I want the countdown to automatically start everyday and end after 24hrs instead of changing the date everyday.

Comment: Actually, I'm a newbie in javascript. I actually bought an html template that has a countdown function included in it. And the countdown is working fine but I want it to automatically start everyday and end after 24hrs instead of changing the date everyday

Comment: I've gotten a solution. Tanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);

var countdown = { startDate: startDate, targetDate: endDate };
```

Comment: @User1594040, Its saying there is a syntax error after pasting the code.

Comment: Actually, I'm a newbie in javascript. I actually bought an html template that has a countdown function included in it. And the countdown is working fine but I want it to automatically start everyday and end after 24hrs instead of changing the date everyday

Comment: its now working fine. Tanks